# Can bought Android apps be shared between devices you own?

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

On the iPod Touch/iPhone, since it is tied to your iTunes account, I am quite sure you can have your bought apps on multiple devices you own (can't test though, iPod Touch was stolen).

However, now I have the Motorola Droid, and am waiting for a tablet, and am considering getting a Nook and rooting it to run my own apps.

Question is, if you buy an app on the marketplace, how is the security done:

1. Is it tied to your Gmail account so you can share it between devices you own?
2. Is it tied to the device? (Don't break/replace your phone!)
3. As long as it's installed, you're OK? (If you uninstall, or wipe your device, it's gone).

I assume 3 is highly unlikely, though a possibility, so leaving it here as a potential answer to my question.

Comment: Just for complement, if you buy an app on App Store, you can only download it on 5 different devices before you have to buy again, while a single purchase on Google Play (formerly Android Market) enables you to download it for unlimited times.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On your phone open the Android Market app, press <kbd>Menu</kbd>, then select Help, then choose Troubleshooting (under Users), you should now see the "Retrieving previously purchased apps" headline. This says:

> Your application purchases are tied to
>   your Google Account and can be
>   installed an unlimited number of times
>   on any device.
>
> ...
>
> If you change devices, you can install
>   previous purchases by making sure you
>   sign into your device with the same
>   Google Account you used on your
>   previous phone.

Answer (score -2):

Not a technical answer, but in the [Android Market Developer Distribution Agreement](http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html) '3.6 Reinstalls' it states that you can (no mention of different devices though).