# Same Apps for multiple tablets

Tags: applications, paid-apps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can bought android apps be shared between devices you own?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11407/can-bought-android-apps-be-shared-between-devices-you-own)

I am thinking about purchasing an android tablet for each of my four young children. If I purchase an app or e-book or book on one tablet, will it download for free onto the other three? Or will I need to re-purchase it for the other three?

Comment: Also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7099/move-paid-apps-between-devices and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2437/can-i-use-multiple-android-devices-with-a-single-google-account

Comment: @eldarerathis all questions should be merged into http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11407/can-bought-android-apps-be-shared-between-devices-you-own imho

Comment: @Flow: Yeah, I'd agree with you there. It's certainly phrased in the most generic and to-the-point manner.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the applications can be downloaded on each device as long as each device uses the same Google account in the Android Market. Your account's ownership of the app persists even if you have to delete it for some reason, such as running out of space.