# How many devices does one purchase of Android app support?

Tags: paid-apps

I have purchased an app from the Play Store. How many times I can install the same app on different Android devices?

Is there a limit?

Comment: How many can you afford?

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): [Can bought Android apps be shared between devices you own?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/11407)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no limit. From [Google Support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113410?hl=en):

> **Downloading previously purchased & downloaded apps**
>
> When you download a paid or free app on Google Play, the app is
>   connected to your Google Account, meaning that you get several
>   benefits:
>
> - If you get a new device, remove an app to free up space, or reset your
>     device, you can reinstall the app without purchasing it again.
> - If you have multiple devices, you can install the app on all of your devices
>     without purchasing the app again.
> - You can quickly find free or paid
>     apps that you previously downloaded.

Answer (score 12):

App purchases are not bound to devices, but to the Google account they've been purchased with. So as long as you use the same Google account on the devices, there should be no limit AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

It's Completely depends upon applications but in most of the cases it is not restricted on devices or mail account,

As SPB launcher etc track your registration so you can't use those app,

But angry birds, etc you can use....It's depends upon app to app

Comment: No. If an app is submitted to the Play Store, it must comply with the Terms Of Service of the Play Store, which as mentioned above is - buy once, use on as many devices linked to that Google Account.

Developers can however choose to restrict their apps from being installed on certain types of devices - as an example, if they have a tablet version of the same app, they won't allow the phone version to be installed on a tablet that you own, thus prompting you to buy the tablet version as well. Uncommon but not unheard of.

Comment: @Amit Modak. How to put an extra layer of security like SPB launcher for app development?

Comment: @Sparx though you are right about policy and all but as of security prospective it's not the case.... Lets say you have a purchased copy of the app...app links your account which is often rear so most of the apps keep a file on your device for verification so take backup of app and that file(Which found in package directory of app depends upon developer) you can have it...and you are free to go...

Comment: @saumilm Hey mate even i am searching for that, spb uses simple registration key, but they keep track of fake serial numbers...By keeping track they are come to know who is using genuine key ....don't know much about it...will get back to you on this..