# On how many devices can you install a paid app purchased from the Amazon App Store?

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps, amazon-appstore

Several questions on Android Enthusiasts (including [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51689/how-many-devices-does-one-purchase-of-android-app-support)) seek to determine on how many different Android devices an app purchased from the Google Play Store can be installed.  The answers provided state that the answer is "unlimited".

What about applications purchased from the Amazon App Store?  Are there limits to the number of devices on which the app can be installed.  Or is it unlimited as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlimited. The [Terms of Use](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201485660) for Amazon's Appstore make no statements regarding number of installs or devices, but it uses the word "copies" to refer to the fact that multiple installations are permitted. The only restriction noted is that you must have the Appstore app installed and you must be signed in to the account that made the purchase:

> Once you have paid for an App, you may download copies of the App for your personal use to compatible Android devices. Each time you download an App to a particular device, you will first be required to download and install the Appstore Software, if it is not already available on the device, and to sign in to the Appstore Software using the user name and password for the Amazon.com customer account that you used to buy the App.