# Paid apps when using 2 Google accounts on a same device?

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

I have seen [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51689/how-many-devices-does-one-purchase-of-android-app-support) that we can use paid apps on several devices because play store apps are saved on a Google account (not on one device).

I have one android device but it will be connected depending on the days to 2 different Google accounts. Some paid apps will be on the first Google account and some others (not the same apps) on the second G. account.

● Will I be able to have all my paid apps on my device all the time?

- Let say Day 1, I buy 2 apps (A and B) with my G. account 1 and install them on my device.
- Day 2 I switch my device to the G. Account 2 and buy 2 more apps (C and D) and install them on my device.
- Day 3, I connect back my device to the G. Account 1. At this point, will I still have on my device the 4 apps (A,B,C,D) that I have paid for?

● Will there be issues occurring from this process during backup, update,...?

Answer (score 1):

I would test the theory first but I think they stay with the device after you sign off. You can also have two accounts signed on the same phone at the same time so your not logging in and out. You toggle them on all the google apps by clicking on your profile pic very much like the PC. If your good with file managing I have only had a few apps that I have paid for that I was not able to just import the file APK and actually share it with other user profiles and they worked just fine, in case you ever just wanted to have all paid on one account. Hope this helps some!