# Can I have more than one tablet on the same email account?

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

I have two tablets for each of my kids and I set them both up with my email account on the app store to get them games. But when trying to use the PC to choose the games for me it will only let me select one of the tablets and not both.

Do I need to have to separate accounts for each of them or is there a way around it?

Comment: There should be a drop-down after you click on "Installed" (or if you haven't installed it yet, "Install"), you should have the option to select which device you want to install it to.  For my 3 devices, I see them listed.  If it is installed already on the device, it'll be grayed out.

Comment: Well, you cannot install the app *simultaneously* to more than one device that way (that drop-down only allows to select one item). Just install the app twice, once on the 1st and then on the 2nd device.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have multiple devices on one email account. When using the Play Store from the PC, it will give you the option of which device you want the app installed to. Once selected, the app will take a few minutes to download and install (depending on Internet reception). After that you can install that same app on ANY other devices you have.

I currently am using a total of 13 devices on one email account for Google Play Store. That's Android on PC, laptops, tablets, Android TV box, and several smartphones. Remember you always can decide which apps you want to install to which device.

**Here are some references**

- [ask-ac-can-i-install-android-apps-more-one-device](http://m.androidcentral.com/ask-ac-can-i-install-android-apps-more-one-device)
- [can-i-use-multiple-android-devices-with-a-single-google-account](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2437/can-i-use-multiple-android-devices-with-a-single-google-account)
- [how-to-share-google-play-apps-music-and-more-between-android-devices/](http://www.howtogeek.com/214555/how-to-share-google-play-apps-music-and-more-between-android-devices/)
- [how-many-devices-does-one-purchase-of-android-app-support](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51689/how-many-devices-does-one-purchase-of-android-app-support)

Answer (score 0):

This should be entirely possible. Try rebooting each device & going into Applications > Google Play Store > clear Data & Cache.

You can also try signing out of the website on your PC and then signing back it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, I think your issue here is in the installation of the software applications? Play only allows you to install to one device at a time, but you should see both tablets in the install drop down menu, let it install on one and then click the "Installed" button and it should present the same menu to select a device, select the seconds tablet and let it install. If you go to the Play Store and select Settings, you should be able to see all your devices associated with your account and the time of last activity, and there is a tick box to either show/hide in the menus, so make sure both tablets are there and ticked to show.