# Android Google Play Install count

Tags: google-play-store

my company need to install one specific apk in 1200 devices

how do they play store count the installation/active?

its per e-mail (all devices will have the same playstore e-mail) or per device?

will be 1200/1200 (by device)

or 1/1 (by e-mail)

Comment: See: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51689/how-many-devices-does-one-purchase-of-android-app-support and

Comment: And https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628#install

Answer (score 1):

Google provides analytics like number of active user, type of device used,version of operating system used.

*I suggest to send a apk directly to specific user*

or

***ask user to signup for the beta version of your app and push company specific code to beta stage and proceed suitably .***